Can I set two different Google Analytics in a Firebase Project?
so we have already built our app using Firebase. We use some services like FCM, Crashlytics, App Distribution etc and we also use Firebase Google Analytics. but recently our company have branch office in another country. so we know have two landing pages let say it is called:

myWebsite.id


myWebsite.sg

the landing pages will be used for digital marketing, and the digital marketing team from the new branch office will use a new Google Analytics on the landing page.
the problem is, now we have two distinguish Google Analytics. one of it has already attached to existing Firebase project (via Firebase Analytics)
my question is, Can I set two different Google Analytics in a Firebase Project? maybe programmatically? I expect I can use only one crashlytics and FCM but we will have two diffrent Google Analytics. can we do that?

You can create multiple apps in one Firebase project, then initialize each of them for each of your landing page. See this documentation for reference.

For web apps, the analytics data is mapped to the Measurement ID
property in the configuration object.
For mobile apps, the analytics data is mapped to the App ID property
in the configuration file.

You can now use the apps or configs that you initialized to create Firebase application instances. For web apps, you can use it to log your analytics data. On the other hand, for mobile apps, the analytics data will only be logged for the default app.
Once data is available to the Analytics dashboard, you may filter the data by stream name dimension.
